# show coordinates by a zoom level google maps

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I have a java script  code in which i am showing coordinates on page load.I want to show those coordinates like if the user is on a zoom level of  15 and higher instead of showing all those coordinates in a page load.Is it possible to tackle this?Below is what am trying but  still not hitting the correct way.
Below is the script i am trying but not getting through

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Maps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater Id="rptMarkers" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                     {
                         "title": '<%# Eval("Title") %>',
                         "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                         "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                         "description": '<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                     }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
            ];
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            window.onload = function () {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var content='<div id="content" style="Width:150px;Height:40px"></div>'
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                    {
                        content:content,
                        width:80,
                        Height:80

                    });
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"), mapOptions);
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var data = markers[i]
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        title: data.title
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(map,"zoom_changed",function(){
                        if(map.getZoom()>15)
                        {

                             //this is where am hoping to display my coordinates
                      }

                    });







                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP)
                    })(marker, data);
                }
            }
        </script>
`enter code here`        <br />
        <div id="Map" style="width: 1050px; margin-left: 90px; height: 800px">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to show your coordinates (you mean POIs?) that fits inside your current zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

You could easy check for each marker if it they are visible at your current zoom level.

```
var markers; // your markerarray
var map; // your map
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
    if( map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition()) ){

       // only load markers which are currently visible in this zoom level

    }
}
```

Comment: have used a sample of that code and shows only one  coordinates and the rest are invisible despite being closer somehow.Where could i be going wrong?here is the code i have tried  from your previous soln `for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition()))
                        {

                            map.setMap(markers);
                        }
                    }
`

Comment: So if you zoom out there is only one marker? Your markerArray contains multiple LatLng positions?

Comment: Is your code in your first post still actual? So you load all your markers on beginning, and if you zoom to level > 15 you want to show new POIs? Or remove POIs they are outside the zoom level?

Comment: yes,on page load am loading all coordinates in the marker array but this is not advisable as it will take more time to show all coordiantes.instead on page load ,if i can get the user zoom level coordinates bound it's rather helpfull.I still want to load the POIs on the current zoom level

Comment: What is the problem now? If you load your page all markers are present? If you zoom to a specific level there is only one marker? Or no marker? You need to remove all markers which are not visible at the current viewport by using: marker[i].setMap(null)

Comment: if i load my page ,only one marker is present,the rest are not loaded,its loading only the first coordinate in the markers array.when i view page source i can see the  other POIs but they are not shown

Comment: Did you use marker.setMap(map); in your for loop through your markers on page load?